# How can I use matlab imadjust function in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to increase the contrast of images by using opencv. However, contrast adjusment functions in opencv do not provide what I want. In Matlab, imadjust function is working perfect for my images. Thus, what is the corresponding of imadjust in opencv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you look for this. Please try this code and let me know if it does not work.

```
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread("Image_path", 1)

    cv2.imshow("Original image",img)

    # CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=1., tileGridSize=(1,1))

    lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # convert from BGR to LAB color space
    l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)  # split on 3 different channels

    l2 = clahe.apply(l)  # apply CLAHE to the L-channel

    lab = cv2.merge((l2,a,b))  # merge channels
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  # convert from LAB to BGR
    img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite('Increased_Contrast.jpg', img3)
    cv2.imshow('Increased contrast', img3)


    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```